# customize _id in rails elasticsearch model export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, elasticsearch

I use MongoId with Elasticsearch::Model in Rails.
By default the _id of elasticsearch is inherited from the model.
How is the best method to customise the _id generation for the elasticsearch indexation

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  
  def as_indexed_json
    as_json
  end

end
```

In MongoDb, the _id value is an object.
I want to hash this object value for _id before sending the _id to elasticsearch.
and instead of an _id like this in elasticsearch:

```
"_id" : """{"indicator"=>"xxxx",  "year"=>2023, "month"=>6, "customer"=>"2143242", "date"=>"2023-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"}"""
```

I want to generate:

```
 "_id": "6349dbf74da2d26cefc5803f6c6e6b99ad7e1a4b"
```